# Sqlite load extension disabled?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to use this [sqlite extension](http://www.sqlite.org/contrib/download/extension-functions.c?get=25) to calculate stdev in Sqlite dbs, on Linux, I use this command to compile the lib

> gcc -fPIC -lm -shared extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.so

but seems that the .load command is not in the sqlite .help command list, and I got error:

> unknown command or invalid arguments:  "load". Enter ".help" for help

Same thing happens when I use the command:

```
 sqlite> SELECT load_extension('./libsqlitefunctions.so');
```

> SQL error: no such function: load_extension

I tried to use this instruction to compile sqlite:

```
0. untar latest sqlite3 source code in a new directory

1. cd to the newly untarred sqlite directory

2. Comment out the line in Makefile.in to enable loadable extensions:

     # TCC += -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1

3. ./configure LIBS=-ldl && make sqlite3

4. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

5. gcc -I`pwd` -shared src/test_loadext.c -o half.so

6. ./sqlite3
```

But couldn't find the line "TCC += -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=1" in the newest Sqlite source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `configure` was updated but not the documentation.  Try

```
./configure --enable-dynamic-extensions
```

The reference is the `configure` source code. Digging further, it looks like the dynamic extensions are enabled by default.  From `README`:

```
The generic installation instructions for autoconf/automake are found  
in the INSTALL file.

The following SQLite specific boolean options are supported:

  --enable-readline           use readline in shell tool   [default=yes]
  --enable-threadsafe         build a thread-safe library  [default=yes]
  --enable-dynamic-extensions support loadable extensions  [default=yes]
```

So I think `load` is present.  It's the second part of the error **invalid arguments** that's the problem.

The cause seems to be that you're using Linux instructions. That won't work. Macs don't generally have `.so` files, which is what your compilation command is generating.

The method of compiling and loading a Mac dynamic library, loadable as an extension, is at [this location](http://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=LoadableExtensions).  The compile command is going to look something like

```
gcc -bundle -fPIC -I/path-to-sqlite/sqlite3 -o filename.sqlext filename.c
```

Note the `-bundle` and `-fPIC` that are important for dynamic loading, but which you were missing.  The resulting filename will be `filename.sqlext`, so use that in your path.

Comment: Thanks, Gene! Actually you are right, this time I got something different: (I used both Mac and Ubuntu to compile sqlite, for consistency, I'll all use Linux here.)

sqlite> SELECT load_extension('./libsqlitefunctions');
Error: ./libsqlitefunctions.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Any idea why this happens?

(The command I used to compile extension-functions.c is:
gcc -fPIC -lm -shared extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.so)

Comment: @JoSmith Well, the documentation implies that you must give the extension. `SELECT load_extension('./libsqlitefunctions.so');`.  Of course this assumes you have the `.so` file in the current directory of your sqlite session.  It's not rocket science.  You must follow the examples precisely.

Comment: How can I enable .load? I'm using MacOS

Comment: I made a question for this, but it got closed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69520945/why-is-load-not-in-my-sqlite3-macos-big-sur

Comment: @Gene I know that your intention here is to help, but please know that when you say things like "it's not rocket science", that's demeaning language and is an all-around unnecessary statement.

Comment: @serverpunk I regret that you find offense here. That sentence literally means "it's not complicated."  That shouldn't be demeaning to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth noting that you may get a "missing symbols" error when you load the library - this is due to the fact that the -lm flag needs to be at the end of the compile command thus:

gcc -fPIC  -shared extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.so -lm

Regards Fat jonnie